# swiftmailer: How do I know there's an issue sending an email?

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

So I was reading the last section of this [page](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html) and it talks about knowing if there's a problem sending an email.

As a test, I use:

1. my personal Gmail acct (I got the email on this one)
2. a fake email using the company domain (e.g. myfakeemailhere123456789@companyB.com). I know it's going to be fake since our company uses some standards for their email address.

and both resulted in returning a blank array.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

edit: I'm using postfix that's locally installed in the server.

Comment: Your fake email will bounce, eventually. PHP won't be involved in that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Swiftmailer ist only for sending mails,

so if you have an issue `sending` the email you could make use of try/catch

BUT it will not receive any mails, so you will not be able to receive and react to a bounce-mail (the mail that will be returned by your company-webserver if the adress doesnt exist)